# Running laravel app using Grunt fails to start session on local environment

Tags: angularjs, session, gruntjs, laravel-5, cors

I am working on an angular-laravel app. I have an API kind of workflow.

[image]

The angular app sits at the root of the project directory in the angular folder.This has the build tools and dependency management tools configured  like bower and grunt.

My `routes.php` has been configured to authenticate the user on login.

```
    Route::post('login','LoginController@auth');
    Route::get('checkAuthentication','LoginController@isLoggedIn');
```

When I call both the routes,I always get the response as false.
Tried printing the values in the `Auth::attempt()` method,which logs in the user,but the session does not persist.The user is immediately thrown out to the home page.
 I start the applcication using `grunt` by running `grunt serve`. This starts the app on `localhost:9000`. I call the laravel routes from angular by giving path to the public folder as they are laravel routes.
 `Example: localhost/project_dir/public/login`. This check the user in database but immediately destroy or does not create session even after adding CORS extension. NO error is displayed.Just `false` is returned and the user is redirected to home page.

```
 Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
 Request URL:http://localhost/project_dir/public/user/check
 Request Method:POST
 Status Code:200 OK
 Response Headers
 view source
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:9000
 Cache-Control:no-cache
 Connection:Keep-Alive
 Content-Length:4
 Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
 Date:Wed, 29 Jul 2015 10:30:33 GMT
 Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
 Server:Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
 Set-  Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InlaVVlxUDRra3E1NXdcL25OekJvSlBRPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlVaWGF6NmdsV1wvZ3NcL1FTVkR5Y2J3czlQNUkyaWdxZlJmeG5zK2U2c0lqM2VOMEY5S000cVwveTBVazBwVFNSZXlhZmhWSEUxUlRyMVJidE5TcE5jM2FBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiIzYzQ2YjJkMjVmMjZiODBiNzgwNmY3YjQ3NmMwOWI5MmM3NmFmZmNmMzY1MDFkNjFlMjg0MjQ0MzVjNGUyYTAzIn0%3D; expires=Wed, 29-Jul-2015 12:30:33 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=http://localhost:9000/;  httponly
 Vary:Origin
 X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.12
 Request Headers
 view source
 Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
 Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
 Cache-Control:max-age=0
 Connection:keep-alive
 Content-Length:0
 Host:localhost
 Origin:http://localhost:9000
 Referer:http://localhost:9000/
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,  like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36 FirePHP/4Chrome
 X-FirePHP-Version:0.0.6
 X-Wf-Max-Combined-Size:261120
```

Above are request response headers for a route to check users session.

**How can I debug it to resolve the issue? Is it angular rejecting the request?**
**Update:**
I tried disabling the `laravel_session` cookie using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624807/disable-cookie-header-when-responding-json) but still no luck

```
 Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://localhost/project_dir/public/user/check
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:9000
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:4
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 29 Jul 2015 13:41:51 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
Vary:Origin
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.12
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: When you calling `api` directly (not from angular).. is session working ?

Comment: Yes it works,actually we had a different workflow earlier.All angular code inside public folder of laravel,and now moved to this workflow to have separation of front and back end. At first we got CORS error but that was fixed after adding laravel extension.But session still fails to persist

Comment: Downvoter please suggest improvements so that I can update!

Comment: Look at the cookies sent in actual requests ... api and front end are on different domains.

Comment: yes thats why I have added the CORS support which should allow the sessions to work right? Please correct if wrong @charlietfl

Comment: CORS has nothing to do with sessions directly.

Comment: Then does laravel block requests from a different domain and prohibit it from starting? why does the session does not persist?

Comment: How can it...you are setting session cookie on another domain. [REST is stateless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Stateless)

Comment: Ok,I get your point but in a testing enviroment or local,how can I configure the grunt setup to work with server requests? What configuration updates do I need?

Comment: To have a working app environment. I mean a angular laravel app,with grunt and bower configured for dependency. After I launch it using grunt serve I can also get the response from server. I mean is their a workflow or setup to achive this or I am being stupid

Comment: Use headers instead of cookies

Comment: So disable cookies on laravel side and work only with headers? Can you point to any example to achieve it?

Comment: @charlietfl Can you add an answer with a potential solution and your views on the module,so that I can close the thread? Thank you for you comments anyways.